# group_by, distinct, and multiple levels of duplicates with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that has 3 hierarchical grouping levels and 4 types of costs.  Group is one to many with project, and project one to many with versions.    `costs2.1a` looks like this (~500krows):

```
+-------+---------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| group | project | versions | amount1  | amount2 | amount3 | amount4 |
+-------+---------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1316 |     142 |        0 |   370662 |  370662 |  288264 |    4688 |
|  1316 |     142 |        1 |   174242 |  174242 |  134837 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        1 |   174242 |  174242 |  134837 |  159242 |
|  1316 |     142 |        2 |  -246912 | -246912 | -191073 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        2 |  -246912 | -246912 | -191073 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        2 |  -246912 | -246912 | -191073 |   60591 |
|  1316 |     142 |        2 |  -246912 | -246912 | -191073 |    5000 |
|  1316 |     142 |        3 |   -32437 |  -32437 |  -25101 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        3 |   -32437 |  -32437 |  -25101 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        3 |   -32437 |  -32437 |  -25101 |       0 |
|  1316 |     142 |        3 |   -32437 |  -32437 |  -25101 |       0 |
|  1316 |     143 |        0 |   620515 |  620515 |  480186 |  411400 |
|  1316 |     143 |        1 |   -31113 |  -31113 |  -24077 |       0 |
|  1316 |     151 |        0 |   515269 |  515269 |  398982 |     510 |
|  1316 |     151 |        1 |    85380 |   85380 |   65213 |   85380 |
+-------+---------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to `group by` the `'group'`, `'project'`, and `'versions'` variables first.  Then I want to remove duplicates across `'amount 1' : 'amount 4'`.  Then, I want to go back and remove duplicates across `'amount 1' : 'amount 3'` (still holding the grouping) `if 'amount 4' = 0`.

I tried to figure out an answer several ways including while loops with if, but the closest I came to an answer is this code:

```
library(dplyr)
costs2.1a <- cbind(mit2.1filter[ , 2:4], costsSub) %>% 
  group_by(DISASTER_NUMBER, PW_NUMBER, VERSION_NUMBER) %>%
  distinct(PROJECT_AMOUNT, TOTAL_ELIGIBLE, TOTAL_OBLIGATED, MITIGATION_COST, .keep_all = TRUE)
costs2.1b <- costs2.1a[which(distinct(costs2.1a, PROJECT_AMOUNT, TOTAL_ELIGIBLE, TOTAL_OBLIGATED, .keep_all = TRUE) & costs2.1a$MITIGATION_COST != 0), ]
```

I know it's not doing what I want because `costs2.1a` has 173,871 rows and `costs2.1b` has 366,968 rows; which doesn't make sense.

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong in this code, or another way to do what I want, the help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Edit**

Heres some dput data, thanks Jazzaro.

```
> dput(head(cbind(mit2.1filter[ , 2:4], costsSub), 30))

structure(list(DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 
1305L, 1305L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 
35L, 70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PROJECT_AMOUNT = c(6787, 
16402, 33843, 28169, 12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 
79755, 39894, 11352, 7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, 
-111638, -14021, 3364, 11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 
0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_ELIGIBLE = c(6787, 16402, 33843, 28169, 
12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 79755, 39894, 11352, 
7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, -111638, -14021, 3364, 
11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_OBLIGATED = c(5347, 
12921, 26320, 21907, 9745, 168768, -117512, 10721, 1306, 46878, 
62026, 31740, 9032, 5984, 2347, 64607, 15855, 2058, 189129, -86391, 
-10850, 2703, 9087, 5994, 139624, -139624, 174030, 0, -49320, 
-49320), MITIGATION_COST = c(1780, 1575, 1500, 6600, 0, 3885, 
0, 6230, 0, 0, 0, 10222, 1410, 1821, 528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27187, 
0, 1050, 3280, 204, 87984, 0, 65000, 0, -65000, 0)), .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
"PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER", "PROJECT_AMOUNT", "TOTAL_ELIGIBLE", 
"TOTAL_OBLIGATED", "MITIGATION_COST"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(costs2.1a, 30))  ##this is output data!!

structure(list(DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 
1305L, 1305L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 
35L, 70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PROJECT_AMOUNT = c(6787, 
16402, 33843, 28169, 12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 
79755, 39894, 11352, 7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, 
-111638, -14021, 3364, 11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 
0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_ELIGIBLE = c(6787, 16402, 33843, 28169, 
12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 79755, 39894, 11352, 
7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, -111638, -14021, 3364, 
11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_OBLIGATED = c(5347, 
12921, 26320, 21907, 9745, 168768, -117512, 10721, 1306, 46878, 
62026, 31740, 9032, 5984, 2347, 64607, 15855, 2058, 189129, -86391, 
-10850, 2703, 9087, 5994, 139624, -139624, 174030, 0, -49320, 
-49320), MITIGATION_COST = c(1780, 1575, 1500, 6600, 0, 3885, 
0, 6230, 0, 0, 0, 10222, 1410, 1821, 528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27187, 
0, 1050, 3280, 204, 87984, 0, 65000, 0, -65000, 0)), .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
"PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER", "PROJECT_AMOUNT", "TOTAL_ELIGIBLE", 
"TOTAL_OBLIGATED", "MITIGATION_COST"), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(
    DISASTER_NUMBER, PW_NUMBER, VERSION_NUMBER), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28:29), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
    1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
    1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 1305L, 1305L, 
    1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 35L, 
    70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
    62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
    1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(DISASTER_NUMBER, PW_NUMBER, 
    VERSION_NUMBER), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
"PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER")))

> dput(droplevels(head(costs2.1a, 30)))  ##this is output data!!

structure(list(DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 
1305L, 1305L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 
35L, 70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PROJECT_AMOUNT = c(6787, 
16402, 33843, 28169, 12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 
79755, 39894, 11352, 7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, 
-111638, -14021, 3364, 11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 
0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_ELIGIBLE = c(6787, 16402, 33843, 28169, 
12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 79755, 39894, 11352, 
7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, -111638, -14021, 3364, 
11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 0, -65000, -65000), TOTAL_OBLIGATED = c(5347, 
12921, 26320, 21907, 9745, 168768, -117512, 10721, 1306, 46878, 
62026, 31740, 9032, 5984, 2347, 64607, 15855, 2058, 189129, -86391, 
-10850, 2703, 9087, 5994, 139624, -139624, 174030, 0, -49320, 
-49320), MITIGATION_COST = c(1780, 1575, 1500, 6600, 0, 3885, 
0, 6230, 0, 0, 0, 10222, 1410, 1821, 528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27187, 
0, 1050, 3280, 204, 87984, 0, 65000, 0, -65000, 0)), .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
"PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER", "PROJECT_AMOUNT", "TOTAL_ELIGIBLE", 
"TOTAL_OBLIGATED", "MITIGATION_COST"), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), vars = list(DISASTER_NUMBER, PW_NUMBER, VERSION_NUMBER), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28:29), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
    1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
    1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 1305L, 1305L, 
    1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 35L, 
    70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
    62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
    1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(DISASTER_NUMBER, PW_NUMBER, 
    VERSION_NUMBER), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
"PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit azzurro.  It wouldn't let me post and kept throwing the auto correct error saying code wasn't formatted properly, but I formatted everything I could as code.  I figured I would try to post with it all blocked off and edit and see if that worked, but you beat me to it : )

Comment: Pleasure to help you. I think you want to provide the data using `dput(costs2.1a)`. Then, you will see a chunk of lines representing the data. If you can upload that, SO users can easily give you a hand.

Comment: your examples throw errors. (`object 'DISASTER_NUMBER' not found`)

Comment: @Sotos,Thanks. I think I fixed the issue. I changed the variables in the code block back to the real variables and added the dput for the initial data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is relatively easy, we reshape with `gather`, use `distinct` to keep only unique values, and reshape back. Note that we completely lose `amount2` because no values are unique in the sample data.

```
d <- costs2.1a %>% 
  gather('key', 'value', amount1:amount4) %>% 
  distinct(group, project, versions, value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

The second part is harder, since we can't use `distinct` conditionally. So we reshape again (`d2`), then use `distinct` on only a subset (`d3`), do nothing on the rest of the data (`d4`), and then bind then together and reshape back.

```
d2 <- d %>% 
  gather('key', 'value', amount1:amount3)

d3 <- d2 %>% 
  filter(amount4 == 0) %>% 
  distinct(group, project, versions, value, .keep_all = TRUE)

d4 <- d2 %>% filter(amount4 != 0)

bind_rows(d3, d4) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

#### Data:

```
costs2.1a <- as.data.frame(structure(list(DISASTER_NUMBER = c(1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 
                                   1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
                                   1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1305L, 
                                   1305L, 1305L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L, 1306L), 
               PW_NUMBER = c(6L, 
                             35L, 70L, 71L, 83L, 121L, 121L, 125L, 9L, 37L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 
                             62L, 65L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 
                             1235L, 1235L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L, 1349L), 
               VERSION_NUMBER = c(0L, 
                                  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                  2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
               PROJECT_AMOUNT = c(6787, 
                                  16402, 33843, 28169, 12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 
                                  79755, 39894, 11352, 7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, 
                                  -111638, -14021, 3364, 11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 
                                  0, -65000, -65000), 
               TOTAL_ELIGIBLE = c(6787, 16402, 33843, 28169, 
                                  12148, 217010, -151101, 13786, 1625, 60260, 79755, 39894, 11352, 
                                  7521, 2950, 82010, 20316, 2646, 243190, -111638, -14021, 3364, 
                                  11421, 7534, 184012, -184012, 229357, 0, -65000, -65000), 
               TOTAL_OBLIGATED = c(5347, 
                                   12921, 26320, 21907, 9745, 168768, -117512, 10721, 1306, 46878, 
                                   62026, 31740, 9032, 5984, 2347, 64607, 15855, 2058, 189129, -86391, 
                                   -10850, 2703, 9087, 5994, 139624, -139624, 174030, 0, -49320, 
                                   -49320), 
               MITIGATION_COST = c(1780, 1575, 1500, 6600, 0, 3885, 
                                   0, 6230, 0, 0, 0, 10222, 1410, 1821, 528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27187, 
                                   0, 1050, 3280, 204, 87984, 0, 65000, 0, -65000, 0)), 
          .Names = c("DISASTER_NUMBER", 
                     "PW_NUMBER", "VERSION_NUMBER", "PROJECT_AMOUNT", "TOTAL_ELIGIBLE", 
                     "TOTAL_OBLIGATED", "MITIGATION_COST"), row.names = c(NA, -30L
                     )))

names(costs2.1a) <- c('group', 'project', 'versions', 'amount1', 'amount2', 'amount3', 'amount4')
```

Comment: You can't use line breaks in comments. Use backticks for code.

Comment: thanks.  If you were using the costs2.1a file wouldn't it already have step one complete so d would do nothing?

Comment: You can check yourself, I included the exact data I used. I lose 1 row, and there are some `NA`s introduced.

Comment: Looking at your data I dont see any NAs.  I got your code to work on the entire dataset and mine has lots of NAs.  I think it has something to do with the fact that a lot of the amount values are the same as you mentioned above.  It seems like in your sample though, amount1 and amount2 are the same but it still shows values for both.  Did you do something that I missed to keep the non unique column values from becoming NAs?

Comment: Are you looking at `d`? Cause that's where I have the NA's. `amount2` completely dissapears, because of the way `spread` works (it should be all NA's for these values, if there would be any values to keep). Cause I took my `costs2.1a` from your question (after changing it so I didn't get the error that Sotos also got.)

Comment: Ahh ok, I was looking at data, I thought it was your data output sorry.  So, It seems like your solution is almost exactly what I need, but I need to keep all the values and not get NAs.  I will look around for a solution to that now, but if you have any ideas I am all ears : )